# Salesforce1 ListView customization

Tags: salesforce1-app

Is there anyway to customize the default listview on the salesforce1?
It seems like it doesn't give you any option to customize the list.

Flexi page is only option that I have?
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kymCAAQ